# How to impliment currentTime

Tags: video, web, video.js

Im trying to use the currenttime function to make my video.js player play from a specific time.

I've put this directly into the html file but when I open the file in the browser the video is still starting from the beginning.  What am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>


     <script>
        videojs("example_video_1").ready(function(){
            var myPlayer = videojs.setup("example_video_1");

            // EXAMPLE: Start playing the video.
            myPlayer.currentTime(200);
            myPlayer.play();

        });
  </script>
```

Edited: to include ending script tag and jquery library...still doesnt work

edit: if you want to see the video.js please download here:
http://www.videojs.com/downloads/video-js-4.1.0.zip

Comment: I assume that it's just a typo, but did you remember to close your `<script>` tag?

Comment: It seems like you're using jQuery, have you included the jQuery library?

Comment: I did close it...just didnt paste it...updating...

Comment: So I updated the post to include jquery library as well as closing script tag, can someone please explain what is "happening" when I instantiate a player and do "myplayer.play()" when I refresh the browser its supposed to jump to the noted time no? (200 seconds)

Comment: Try this, add a console.log of myPlayer right before you try to set the current time. Then look in your JavaScript console, what is its value

Comment: Try looking in your JavaScript console (Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome). Any errors?

Comment: You could also try to put this line of code in right before your comment: `console.log(myPlayer);` and see what value it is returning in the JavaScript console.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object function u(a,c,d){if("string"===typeof a){0===a.indexOf("#")&&(a=a.slice(1));if(u.va[a])return u.va[a];a=u.r(a)}if(!a||!a.nodeName)throw new TypeError("The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs)");return a.player||new u.C(a,c,d)} has no method 'setup'

Comment: Not sure what this means, the video.js file is clearly referenced. So that method should be available.

Comment: What is in your video.js file? (Please put in your question, not down here)

Comment: The video.js is enormous...it can be downloaded here: http://www.videojs.com/downloads/video-js-4.1.0.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding event listener.

```
document.getElementById("myVideo").addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    this.currentTime = 29;
  }, false);
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "setup" function in the videojs api. You should check that your video is seekable, and then you should modify your initialization code.

1. You should make sure that its an issue with video js and not your video file / browser / etc.

   ```
   <script>
     var video = document.getElementById("example_video_1");
     video.currentTime = 200;
     video.play();
   </script>
   ```
2. If the above works, then the correct way to do what you're trying to do is:

   ```
   <script>
     videojs("example_video_1", {}, function() {
       this.currentTime(200);
       this.play();
     });
   </script>
   ```